# MySQL trigger not working. What could be the issue?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I need to update an existing table after insert on another table. This is what I have.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `some_trigger`
AFTER INSERT ON `old_table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `new_table` set `some_column` = new.`column`
WHERE `new_table`.id = new.id
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Trigger definition successfully executed and trigger exists with
SQL_MODE - NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
DEFINER - root@%

Is there something horribly wrong with this?

Comment: is there any error or its just not updating the row ?

Comment: @AmanAggarwal - no error! Just not updating the row.

Comment: Which table exiting entry??

Comment: check if new.id is present in new_table

Comment: @AmanAggarwal - yes, it is present in the new_table. That's why the whole issue!

Comment: because i had the same issue in which i am inserting the id in new table after the old table so that trigger not able to find in between..

Comment: @MukeshKalgude - Didn't understand?

Comment: ok i understand id column should be identity column and how to inserted this column?

Comment: @AmanAggarwal - this is not the issue. I double-checked.

Comment: its better to give table definations

Comment: is the trigger created successfully because i think update statement needs a semicolon at the end..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm that the new.id i.e the id generated on old_table insertion is also present in the new table ?
Because the possible reason could be that in new table new.id is not present at the time on old_table insertion.